# How to turn a decimaled number into a framerate designation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

I am using the flowplayer video player and a flowplayer function is giving me a decimal for the point on the player timeline.  i.e. Instead of giving me a traditional:

```
 00:00:01:03
```

timestamp, it just gives me

```
 1.03333
```

or the equivalent.  The

```
 .033333
```

essentially serves as the frames although I believe it is, in that case based on a 10 fps framerate (which is fine for what I am doing.)

I am not skilled at all in working with numbers/decimals in JS.  How can I convert  that

```
 1.033333
```

into a timestamp like

```
 00:00:01:03?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use division and modulus: `x % 60` will give you the remainder of dividing by 60 (`363 % 60` is `3`), then floor divide (`Math.floor(363 / 60)` is `6`) and use modulus again, repeat.

So:

```
var timestamp = 1.03333;
var seconds = timestamp % 60;
timestamp = Math.floor(timestamp / 60);
var minutes = timestamp % 60;
timestamp = Math.floor(timestamp / 60);
var hours = timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrea!  So, I see how to get seconds, minutes and hours, but what about frames?  i.e. .03 would be the frames parameter?

Comment: @CRAIG Oh, you can just do `timestamp % 1` to get the fractional bit, and multiply it as necessary (30x?)